# Unable to change Event Date in Series Event

Tags: event, calendar

I created a daily recurring event for 5 days in Salesforce  3/30 - 4/3 (see screenshot). It created 5 events for each day.

Now when I go and edit the event for tomorrow 3/31 and change the start and end date to 4/1 or any date between 3/30 or 4/3 or before 3/30 or after 4/1, Salesforce doesn't let me change it. 
I get the following error:

**"Select a date that falls between the previous and next events in this series"**

I am trying to understand WHY I can't update the date-time of the event that is recurring. 
Anyone has seen this before? 
Any documentation in this regard?

Comment: Is this in Lightning or Classic? You might find the [considerations](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=creating_events_lex.htm&type=5) for "event series" helpful

Comment: @krish I'm trying to edit an individual event in a series in Lightning and trying to update Start/End datetime. But Salesforce throws an error. Why?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is expected. Your best bet might be to delete the series and create a new one if the dates have changed significantly.

In Lightning, based on the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=creating_events_lex.htm&type=5) you can't do the following:

> - Events in a series can't be made to overlap with other events in the    series.

You're attempting to edit one event to start on a different date, *but there's already an event on those dates* (since it happens on every day from 3/30 - 4/3). That's why you you receive that message: **"Select a date that falls between the previous and next events in this series"**

> - You can’t edit the series from events that fall outside of the series    pattern.
> - You can’t edit the start date of a series. Instead, delete the series and recreate it with a new start date.

You also can't change one event within the series to start outside of the range of dates the event series is set up for. Nor can you change the start date of the series (3/30). *This is why you cannot make it start before 3/30 or after 4/3.*